# Linkify + textIsSelectable

Tags: android, linkify

After using

```
Linkify.addLinks(content, pattern_glos, scheme_glos, null, glosFilter);
```

logs write

```
11-22 21:19:15.319: W/TextView(14718): TextView does not support text selection. 
  Action mode cancelled.
```

And text is not selectable.
I need both and links and selectable.

Comment: I have answered how to do this on the page of a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16003280/427225 Though you can use the `autoLink` attribute as other users suggested, it has some bugs, that's why my answer is preferrable.

Answer (score 1):

To make links in a `TextView` clickable, you need to call `textView.setLinksClickable(true);` and `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`