# Can a TextView be selectable AND contain links?

Tags: android, textview

I've run into a problem with `TextView`. I can make it selectable using `setTextIsSelectable(true)`, but when I enable links to be clicked via `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())`, it is no longer selectable.

Please note, I don't mean making raw links clickable, but rather making actual words clickable by loading the `TextView` with HTML markup using something like `setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Hello World!</a>"))`.

Comment: did you try with Linkify?

Comment: According to the docs, `Linkify` only works on text with URL scheme prefixes, not for arbitrary text that you want to turn into links.

Comment: I think you have to create Custom TextView

Comment: Would it be possible to subclass LinkMovementMethod and modify it to allow selection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TextView that is linkified and selectable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862750/textview-that-is-linkified-and-selectable)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to subclass LinkMovementMethod and add support for text selection. It's really unfortunate that it doesn't support it natively. I just overrode the relevant methods using the equivalent ones from the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/text/method/ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java?av=f) for `ArrowKeyMovementMethod`. I guess that's one benefit of Android being open source!

```
public class CustomMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod {
    @Override
    public boolean canSelectArbitrarily () {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(TextView widget, Spannable text) {
        Selection.setSelection(text, text.length());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTakeFocus(TextView view, Spannable text, int dir) {
       if ((dir & (View.FOCUS_FORWARD | View.FOCUS_DOWN)) != 0) {
           if (view.getLayout() == null) {
               // This shouldn't be null, but do something sensible if it is.
               Selection.setSelection(text, text.length());
           }
       } else {
           Selection.setSelection(text, text.length());
       }
    }
}
```

To use it, just instantiate it directly, like so:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new CustomMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Dude, you're awesome! I was starting to think this was impossible but then I stumbled upon your question. Gotta love Open Source!

Comment: For us this worked, but we had to set textIsSelectable to true

Comment: FYI, this solution sometimes cause "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0" in some cases, for example on double tap on Nexus 5 devices.

Comment: Perfect! You saved my day.

Comment: unfortunately it didnt work for me - tested on 2 devices - Galaxy note 2 and Samsung XPeria Z, tried setMovementMethod(CustomMovementMethod.getInstance()); and setMovementMethod(new CustomMovementMethod());

Comment: @Vang I had the same problem; The exception you've mentioned is pure android coused exception.
When I take a look at it, the specific exception case was to set "textIsSelectable" parameter through the xml file or before the "setMovementMethod" function.

Answer (score 26):

[oakes's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836306/can-a-textview-be-selectable-and-contain-links/15844339#15844339) answer cause exception on double tap on textview

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0...
```

I looked at the *onTouchEvent* impletentation in *LinkMovementMethod* and found that it removes selection when textview doesn't contain link. In this case selection starts from empty value and application crash when user try to change it.

```
...
if (link.length != 0) {
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        link[0].onClick(widget);
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Selection.setSelection(buffer,
        buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]),
        buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
    }
  return true;
} else {
  Selection.removeSelection(buffer);
}
...
```

So i override *onTouchEvent* method,  and it works fine.

```
public class CustomMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod {
    @Override
    public boolean canSelectArbitrarily () {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(TextView widget, Spannable text) {
        Selection.setSelection(text, text.length());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTakeFocus(TextView view, Spannable text, int dir) {
        if ((dir & (View.FOCUS_FORWARD | View.FOCUS_DOWN)) != 0) {
            if (view.getLayout() == null) {
                // This shouldn't be null, but do something sensible if it is.
                Selection.setSelection(text, text.length());
            }
        } else {
            Selection.setSelection(text, text.length());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer,
                                MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
            y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

            x += widget.getScrollX();
            y += widget.getScrollY();

            Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

            ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off, ClickableSpan.class);

            if (link.length != 0) {
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    link[0].onClick(widget);
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Selection.setSelection(buffer,
                            buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]),
                            buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        return Touch.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: This solution WORKED for me rather then next one! Thank you very much for sharing - you saved my day! Tested on 2 devices.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: Simply use the `LinkArrowKeyMovementMethod` at the end of this answer for a perfect solution.**

There is an annoying bug if you ever tried to used the top-voted answers that extends `LinkMovementMethod` -- when you cancel a selection by clicking some text that's not selected, the whole selection flashes to be from the very beginning to the selection end, and then becomes nothing. This is because `LinkMovementMethod` cannot actually handle selection as good as `ArrowKeyMovementMethod`.

Another way around could have been using `TextView`'s own workaround if you have set `android:autoLink` to `true`, as in the following source from `TextView`:

```
        final boolean textIsSelectable = isTextSelectable();
        if (touchIsFinished && mLinksClickable && mAutoLinkMask != 0 && textIsSelectable) {
            // The LinkMovementMethod which should handle taps on links has not been installed
            // on non editable text that support text selection.
            // We reproduce its behavior here to open links for these.
            ClickableSpan[] links = ((Spannable) mText).getSpans(getSelectionStart(),
                getSelectionEnd(), ClickableSpan.class);

            if (links.length > 0) {
                links[0].onClick(this);
                handled = true;
            }
        }
```

But I personally don't want the auto link feature (I have my own link information), so building upon @Weidian Huang 's idea, I incorporated `LinkMovementMethod`'s functionality into `ArrowKeyMovementMethod` and built a new movement method:

```
/**
 * @see LinkMovementMethod
 * @see ArrowKeyMovementMethod
 */
public class LinkArrowKeyMovementMethod extends ArrowKeyMovementMethod {

    private static final int CLICK = 1;
    private static final int UP = 2;
    private static final int DOWN = 3;

    private static Object FROM_BELOW = new NoCopySpan.Concrete();

    private static LinkArrowKeyMovementMethod sInstance;

    public static LinkArrowKeyMovementMethod getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new LinkArrowKeyMovementMethod();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(TextView widget, Spannable text) {
        super.initialize(widget, text);

        text.removeSpan(FROM_BELOW);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTakeFocus(TextView view, Spannable text, int dir) {
        super.onTakeFocus(view, text, dir);

        if ((dir & View.FOCUS_BACKWARD) != 0) {
            text.setSpan(FROM_BELOW, 0, 0, Spannable.SPAN_POINT_POINT);
        } else {
            text.removeSpan(FROM_BELOW);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean handleMovementKey(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, int keyCode,
                                        int movementMetaState, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                if (KeyEvent.metaStateHasNoModifiers(movementMetaState)) {
                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                            event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && action(CLICK, widget, buffer)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.handleMovementKey(widget, buffer, keyCode, movementMetaState, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean up(TextView widget, Spannable buffer) {
        if (action(UP, widget, buffer)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.up(widget, buffer);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean down(TextView widget, Spannable buffer) {
        if (action(DOWN, widget, buffer)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.down(widget, buffer);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean left(TextView widget, Spannable buffer) {
        if (action(UP, widget, buffer)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.left(widget, buffer);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean right(TextView widget, Spannable buffer) {
        if (action(DOWN, widget, buffer)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.right(widget, buffer);
    }

    private boolean action(int what, TextView widget, Spannable buffer) {
        Layout layout = widget.getLayout();

        int padding = widget.getTotalPaddingTop() +
                widget.getTotalPaddingBottom();
        int areaTop = widget.getScrollY();
        int areaBot = areaTop + widget.getHeight() - padding;

        int lineTop = layout.getLineForVertical(areaTop);
        int lineBot = layout.getLineForVertical(areaBot);

        int first = layout.getLineStart(lineTop);
        int last = layout.getLineEnd(lineBot);

        ClickableSpan[] candidates = buffer.getSpans(first, last, ClickableSpan.class);

        int a = Selection.getSelectionStart(buffer);
        int b = Selection.getSelectionEnd(buffer);

        int selStart = Math.min(a, b);
        int selEnd = Math.max(a, b);

        if (selStart < 0) {
            if (buffer.getSpanStart(FROM_BELOW) >= 0) {
                selStart = selEnd = buffer.length();
            }
        }

        if (selStart > last)
            selStart = selEnd = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if (selEnd < first)
            selStart = selEnd = -1;

        switch (what) {
            case CLICK:
                if (selStart == selEnd) {
                    return false;
                }

                ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(selStart, selEnd, ClickableSpan.class);

                if (link.length != 1)
                    return false;

                link[0].onClick(widget);
                break;

            case UP:
                int bestStart, bestEnd;

                bestStart = -1;
                bestEnd = -1;

                for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
                    int end = buffer.getSpanEnd(candidates[i]);

                    if (end < selEnd || selStart == selEnd) {
                        if (end > bestEnd) {
                            bestStart = buffer.getSpanStart(candidates[i]);
                            bestEnd = end;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (bestStart >= 0) {
                    Selection.setSelection(buffer, bestEnd, bestStart);
                    return true;
                }

                break;

            case DOWN:
                bestStart = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                bestEnd = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

                for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
                    int start = buffer.getSpanStart(candidates[i]);

                    if (start > selStart || selStart == selEnd) {
                        if (start < bestStart) {
                            bestStart = start;
                            bestEnd = buffer.getSpanEnd(candidates[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (bestEnd < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    Selection.setSelection(buffer, bestStart, bestEnd);
                    return true;
                }

                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
            y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

            x += widget.getScrollX();
            y += widget.getScrollY();

            Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

            ClickableSpan[] links = buffer.getSpans(off, off, ClickableSpan.class);

            if (links.length != 0) {
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    links[0].onClick(widget);
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Selection.setSelection(buffer,
                            buffer.getSpanStart(links[0]),
                            buffer.getSpanEnd(links[0]));
                }
                return true;
            }
            // Removed
            //else {
            //    Selection.removeSelection(buffer);
            //}
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
    }
}
```

To use it, simply call:

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

And this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

The XML TextView should not have any link or any attributes that can be selected:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then, set everything programmatically respecting the following order:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtml));
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true); // API-11 and above
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Didn't expect this ordering fix to work, but it does!

Answer (score 2):

`LinkMovementMethod()` does not support text selection very well, even we can select the text, but after we scroll the textview, the selection will be lost.

The best implementation is extending from `ArrowKeyMovementMethod`, which supports the text selection very well.

Please see the details in [here](https://hwdtech.wordpress.com/2015/09/19/android-textview-from-html-with-clickable-links-and-text-selection/)

Answer (score 2):

Also, order matters

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Allows the content to be selectable and link clicks working just perfect

Answer (score -1):

would it be possible to associate the TextView with a URL?
Is you have 10 TextView and 10 URLs it should be simple to write code that if TextView[3] is clicked it fires off an intent for webview (or browser) with URL[3]

Comment: Unfortunately no, I need the ability to have multiple links potentially in a `TextView`, just as in normal HTML markup. I know I could use a `WebView`, but I'm trying to avoid such a resource-heavy control.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my take on it for Kotlin (loosely based on @hai-zhang's answer). **Simplified**! See my gist for the better version. I currently use it for custom spans, not the HTML, and it is still relevant for me, especially when I need to pass the position of the user click to the span object.

You need to set the movement method **after** setTextIsSelectable(true)

```
/** Minimal version of Smart Movement that only has limited support of [ClickableSpan] */
object SmartMovementMethodMinimal : ArrowKeyMovementMethod() {

    override fun onTouchEvent(widget: TextView?, buffer: Spannable?, event: MotionEvent?) =
        handleMotion(event!!, widget!!, buffer!!) || super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event)

    private fun handleMotion(event: MotionEvent, widget: TextView, buffer: Spannable): Boolean {
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // Get click position
            val target = Point().apply {
                x = event.x.toInt() - widget.totalPaddingLeft + widget.scrollX
                y = event.y.toInt() - widget.totalPaddingTop + widget.scrollY
            }

            // Get span line and offset
            val line = widget.layout.getLineForVertical(target.y)
            val offset = widget.layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, target.x.toFloat())

            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                val spans = buffer.getSpans<ClickableSpan>(offset, offset)
                if (spans.isNotEmpty()) {
                    spans.forEach { it.onClick(widget) }
                    return true
                }
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

More detailed and complex code with examples here: https://gist.github.com/sQu1rr/210f7e08dd939fa30dcd2209177ba875