# Link spans are lost from ListView's convertView

Tags: android, listview, textview, linkify, spannablestring

Why links in `ListView` are lost, when scrolling? From debugging it's clear, that spans are not added second time on a `TextView` from the `convertView`.

Here's a piece of code which is called from adapter's `getView`.

```
    ...
    String body = MyItemDetails.getBody(); // String to linkify

    final Spannable spannable = MyCustomUri.addHashtagSpans(context, body);
    viewHolder.textView.setText(spannable);

    viewHolder.textView.setTextIsSelectable(true); // adds additional spans
    viewHolder.textView.setMovementMethod(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance());
    viewHolder.textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    ...
```

`MyCustomUri.addHashtagSpans()` creates a `SpannableString` with `MyCustomSpan` with extends `URLSpan`.

Problem is that when I scroll up and down in the `ListView` links are lost. Whereas when screen is opened 1st time it's set correctly.

Now I made a dirty fix by disabling reuse of `convertView` :( Any ideas how to solve this problem better?

Comment: Please post your full code for getView method (or bindView and newView if you are extending CursorAdapter).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the spannable information is likely being lost when the textview's data is written to a parcel for retention.

See [TextView.onSaveInstanceState()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L3474), [TextView.onRestoreInstanceState()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L3535), and [TextView.SavedState](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L8871).

It can often be very frustrating to determine what android will and will not retain. I often just `setSaveEnabled(false)` on my views to disable the unpredictable default behaviours of the base widgets.

Also, the viewholder pattern is only really intended for retaining view/layout instance hierarchies. To save you from having to inflate or find your views every `getView()`. It's always your responsibility to update a view's data when presenting it from `getView()`.

You don't need to completely disable the viewholder pattern, instead just simply update the text every `getView()`, as you may already be doing.

Comment: Tried `setSaveEnabled(false)`, but did not help :(

Comment: Ya that's just an aside. It's not going to solve the problem directly

Comment: The point is that you cannot always rely on android to retain your view state and should be in the habit of doing it yourself.

Comment: So is there a way to reset `TextView`'s state?

Comment: sure, `TextView.setText()`. From the [SavedState](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L8871) class we can see that this is pretty much all that's retained.

Comment: The persistence of data through configuration changes using SavedState and view recycling are two very different mechanisms.  None of this applies to how `ListView` reuses view elements in `getView()`.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Use this custom class

```
public class MyCustomSpannable extends ClickableSpan {
String Url;
Context mContext;

public MyCustomSpannable(String Url, Context context) {
    this.Url = Url;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    // Customize your Text Look if required
    ds.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red_text));
    ds.setFakeBoldText(true);
    // ds.setStrikeThruText(true);
    ds.setTypeface(CommonFunctios.getfontNormal(mContext));
    // ds.setUnderlineText(true);
    // ds.setShadowLayer(10, 1, 1, Color.WHITE);
    // ds.setTextSize(15);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View widget) {
}

public String getUrl() {
    return Url;
}
}
```

and in adapter replace your code with this

```
String text = holder.txt_terms.getText().toString();
SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
MyCustomSpannable customSpannable = new MyCustomSpannable(text,
            mcontext) {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Log.e("on click", "message");
            ((OpticalOffersActivity) mcontext).callDialogBox(position);
        }
    };
    stringBuilder.setSpan(customSpannable, 0, text.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

    holder.txt_terms.setText(stringBuilder, BufferType.SPANNABLE.SPANNABLE);
    holder.txt_terms.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(convertView==null)
    {

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
else
    {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }




 ...
        String body = MyItemDetails.getBody(); // String to linkify

        final Spannable spannable = MyCustomUri.addHashtagSpans(context, body);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(spannable);

        viewHolder.textView.setTextIsSelectable(true); // adds additional spans
        viewHolder.textView.setMovementMethod(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance());
        viewHolder.textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        ...
```

That spannable code must be placed outside the if-else loop in the `getView()` method, like the way I did it in the above code.

Comment: That's true, I've placed spannable code outside if-else block. Issue comes when convertView is reused. `MyCustomUri` spans are not added second time.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems at play here, so let me address them one at a time.  The issues you've asked about directly (links disappearing) is a side effect of the fact that the auto linking behavior in `TextView` doesn't necessarily work that well when you are also adding your own spans to the text manually...best not to use it.  Remove the `setAutoLinkMask()` trigger and the disappearing links issue will go away.

Instead, you can easily add the same web linking behavior directly into your text span with `Linkify`.  However, this is only part of your problem.  The `MovementMethod` you have chosen isn't really compatible with clickable links.  The reason it (partially) works in your code now is because the auto link mask is causing the `MovementMethod` of the view to be secretly massaged under the hood to a `LinkMovementMethod`...which then gets reset after the view is recycled.  A pattern I typically use (applied to your code example) would be:

```
final Spannable spannable = MyCustomUri.addHashtagSpans(context, body);
Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
viewHolder.textView.setText(spannable);

addLinkMovementMethod(textView);
```

Where `addLinkMovementMethod()` is a helper I have that looks like this:

```
private void addLinkMovementMethod(TextView t) {
    MovementMethod m = t.getMovementMethod();

    if ((m == null) || !(m instanceof LinkMovementMethod)) {
        if (t.getLinksClickable()) {
            t.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }
}
```

This simply keeps from resetting the value on each view recycle if it isn't necessary.  The previous code block will give you links that click properly and never disappear...

However, I'm guessing from the methods you've called that you are also attempting to make the linked text in the list selectable (e.g. calling `setTextIsSelectable()` and choosing the `ArrowKeyMovementMethod`).  This gets a little trickier because of the `MovementMethod` issue I discussed above.  In order to create a `MovementMethod` that supports both link clicks and text selection, I'll direct you to this existing SO post on the subject which includes sample code on the customizations you need to make: [Can a TextView be selectable AND contain links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836306/can-a-textview-be-selectable-and-contain-links)

Comment: This looks promising solution. Will try it.